# Basic Website for Verifying Connectivity

Tags: networking, website

I sometimes find myself needing to go to a webpage to verify connectivity or the operation of some system. Many people use something like google.com, but that has more code in the landing page alone than the original Zork. The code I am dealing with today is very slow and an alternative is needed.

I used to use something.com which at one time looked like this https://web.archive.org/web/20170215195653/http://www.something.com/ but the landing page seems to now be gone. It was very useful for testing connectivity, and in today's case, code. Is there another example out there of a basic and easy to type website?

Comment: I found this gem from some deeeep googling https://webappa.cdc.gov/sasweb/dispatch/webhello.htm It is pretty close to what I need, though if there is one with a shorter or more memorable URL that would be best.

Comment: This was closed as off-topic because it is seeking a "product, service, or learning material recommendations". This is incorrect, it is none of these, at least not more so than any other question on here. As for the transience of the solution, example.com is actually guaranteed by RFC 2606 and maintained my ICAAN.

Comment: The fact that example.com is reserved for documentation and will never be used for a “real” website is guaranteed. The fact that there actually ***is*** a live website by that name is not so clearly guaranteed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't get much simpler than https://example.com. Also works with http//.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can probably try:

```
www.google.com/generate_204
```

This URL returns a 204 HTTP code and no content. It should be very fast for testing connectivity.

Or else:

```
www.google.com/robots.txt
```

Comment: (1) The `generate_204` URL gives me a blank page.  I guess that’s the expected result, but ISTM that it doesn’t exactly make it clear that you’re connected to the Internet.  (2) The `robots.txt` file is too big to fit on the screen.  The OP wants a small file.  (Yes, I realize that an eight-page `txt` file can be fewer bytes than a one-page HTML file.)